# dataTable editable cell not responding to double click event

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatable

I have a dataTable defined as

```
<table id="table1"></table>

$('#table1').dataTable({
    /*definition goes here*/
});
```

The table is currently editable using the KeyTables plugin.

However, I want to make it editable on double click

I tried

```
$('#table1 tbody tr td').dblclick(function(){
    var e = jQuery.Event('keypress');
    e.keyCode = 13;
    e.which = 13;
    $(this).trigger(e);
});
```

However, this does not trigger the enter key event on the dataTable cell.

Answer (score 1):

Well the `tr` in the table generated dynamically so it won't get the event binding that way, so you could use `event delegation` with the use of `.on()` method:

```
$('#table1').on('dblclick', 'td', function(){
```

This is a specific syntax for delegating the event to the closest static parent.

```
$(staticParent).on(event, selector, callback);
```